# C# Clipboard Help

Tags: c#, excel, clipboard

I am copying the contents of an Excel file onto the Clipboard within a program I have written.  I can then use that data in memory rather than 'chatting' constantly with Excel.

When I have finished with the data, I cal a cleanup method that calls Clipboard.Clear() first and then closes all Excel sheets/workbooks/apps, etc.

The problem is, even though I clear the Clipboard prior to closing the Excel sheets, I get a pop up window still saying there is substantial amount of data on the clipboard.  Anybody know why?

Thanks,

Darren.

Comment: Could you please share some code with us, so that we know exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why that happens, but have you tried setting `_Application.DisplayAlerts = false;` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts%28office.11%29.aspx)) before you close the sheets to see if that prevents the warning message?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the Excel [`CutCopyMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177432%28office.12%29.aspx) to cancel the current copy information:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = false;
```

Another thought is to set the clipboard to `String.Empty` so the amount of data copied is small enough that it bypasses the warning popup. This may have to be done from the Excel sheet, not the regular clipboard (i.e., copy a cell from the active sheet in Excel).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use

Application.CutCopyMode = false;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839532.aspx

Comment: Application.DisplayAlerts = false, works perfectly.  Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Well at the end, try copying an empty string in clipboard and leave it, then Excel may not give any warning. But use Excel API to copy empty string in clipboard.